# Get the indexes of the adjacent elements smaller or equal to a threshold in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, sorting

I have a sorted array of distances, e.g.:

```
d = np.linspace(0.5, 50, 200)
```

and I want to iteratively get the indexes of adjacent elements that are at a distance smaller or equal than `L` for each element of `d`.
Is there any simple way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.argwhere](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) after checking that consecutive differences are less than or equal to `L`:

```
import numpy as np

np.argwhere((d[1:]-d[:-1])<=L)
```